# jQuery: create any new object after creation of one object

Tags: jquery, object, event-handling, thickbox, oncreate

I want to insert one object like `$('<p>Test</p>').prependTo('#TB_window');` just whenever **#TB_window** object is created.

How it can be made after the creation of a  `thickbox`?

I want to use that in the wordpress site http://hogdal.dk/?p=60

Just see the pictures in the gallery.

I am using wordpress default thickbox.

Comment: can you show the creation code

Comment: just a note thickbox it is not supported now, you can use fancybox instead,
check this for alternatives:  http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Comment: @3nigma: I want to use that in the wordpress site http://hogdal.dk/?p=60
Just see the pictures in the gallery

Comment: @Faddel Homsi: I am using wordpress default thickbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/YZwRu/

```
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);

    if ($target.is('#TB_window')) {
        $target.append('<p>Test</p>');
    }
});

$('body').append('<p>a</p>');
$('body').append('<p id="TB_window">b</p>');
$('body').append('<p>c</p>');
​
```

In this example we use [DOMNodeInserted](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) event, which is triggered when another node is inserted into document. After that we check if that element has the required `id`, and if so - `append` new node to it

Comment: Error: $(document).on is not a function in Error Console

Comment: @Sazzad Tushar Khan: for jquery < 1.7 use `.bind()` instead of `.on()`

Comment: @Sazzad Tushar Khan: there is no issues with the code and jquery 1.7.1. http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/YZwRu/1/ - it works perfectly. Please double check your version. You can check it in runtime with `alert($.fn.jquery)​;`

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery('body').append('<p id="TB_window">Test</p>');

});

jQuery(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
 var target = jQuery(event.target);

 if (target.is('#TB_window')) {
  target.append('<p>Test2</p>');
 }
});

Comment: $target should be replaced by only target

Comment: @Sazzad Tushar Khan: "should"? Any reason for that?

Comment: May be because its not PHP and its jQuery

Comment: @Sazzad Tushar Khan: it is javasctipt, and `$target` is perfectly valid name

Comment: But its not working with me may be because i am using that in a PHP file in Wordpress